# Does spark1.6(Pre-build for Hadoop 2.6) supports hive?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, prebuild

As the website description:

> However, since Hive has a large number of dependencies, it is not included in the default Spark assembly.--http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-tables

So,does spark1.6(Pre-build for Hadoop 2.6) which downloaded from http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html  supports hive? How can i confirm it?

Comment: According to the document, it is not included in the default binary. You can enable it by custom build -Phive.

Comment: I know that,but i can connect to hive with pre-built spark and query on sql successfully, it is contradictory.

Comment: Checked with pom.xml, hive-exec and hive-metastore are included by default. And -Phive does not add more packages. While -Phive-thriftserver does add hive-cli, hive-jdbc and hive-beeline.

Comment: With pre-built spark,I can connect to hive by beeline,but document descrbe that hive is not included in the default Spark assembly,is the document wrong?